# Caffe2 installed correct but can't load glog library

Tags: caffe2

I pip installed caffe2 via a "Prebuilt Caffe2 Python Wheel" without an error. But running the first example I get the following error message which seems not be able to find/load "/usr/local/opt/glog/lib/libglog.0.dylib".

If I import caffe2.python it does not give me an error. 
The glog is missing in usr/local/opt.

Is this a Mac GPU problem ? I know that CUDA is a problem/does not run on Mac or is there anything else I missed/I have to do. ?

Thanks for any help.

```
 WARNING:root:This caffe2 python run does not have GPU support. Will run in CPU only mode.
    WARNING:root:Debug message: No module named caffe2_pybind11_state_gpu
    CRITICAL:root:Cannot load caffe2.python. Error: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe2/python/caffe2_pybind11_state.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/glog/lib/libglog.0.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/caffe2/python/caffe2_pybind11_state.so
      Reason: image not found
```